# MySQL Database Manager with RabbitMQ

Tags: mysql, database, rabbitmq

I'm new to message brokers like RabbitMQ and I have to develop an application with RabbitMQ that interfaces with MySQL, so the final task is to create a MySQL Database Manager.

What language / program do I have to use to complete my task ?

What steps do I have to do to reach my goal ? I want to clarify that **I'm not asking to do it for me**, but just know what are the objective to reach to complete it.

Thank you very much to all of you for the help !

Comment: You shouldn't have to create a Database Manager. May be what you mean is to create a database. Try installing MySql or MariaDB or use XAMP/WAMP package to install MariaDB and then you can create database using phpmyadmin.

Then I guess you can provide RabiitMQ with the database configs to connect to that. Hope this helps

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.